# Add my app to tvOS app settings screen

Tags: ios, tvos

How do you add app settings to tvOS like you do in iOS.
I assume that just like iOS the screen below, you can add the settings for your own application
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a Settings Bundle in tvOS section in Xcode, but you can select the Settings Bundle from iOS section, it's a bit tricky but it definitely works.

**1. File -> New -> File**

**2. iOS -> Resource -> Settings Bundle**

[image: Settings Bundle from iOS Section]

**3. Edit your Bundle Settings plist**

**4. Build and Run**

***N.B.*** tvOS and Xcode 7.1 now is in beta, maybe Apple will add "Settings Bundle" item in tvOS section in the stable release.

Answer (score 3):

tvOS Settings bundle is now available in the tvOS resources section:

[image]

As @pakizip explains, add this to your project and edit the Settings bundle plist file to add custom settings.

Here are the relevant documentation pages for tvOS:

tvOS Preferences and Settings

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html

Implementing an iOS settings bundle

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html