# What template can I use for a tvOS app system settings, since it's not included anymore?

Tags: xcode, tvos

I have a tvOS application that has some settings that can be set to change some parameters for the app. In older versions of Xcode, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36605516/1118321) points out, there was a specific template for a Systems Settings bundle for tvOS. In Xcode 10, targeting tvOS 12, there is no such template anymore. The [documentation for System Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007005-SW1) says it is no longer being maintained,  but there's no link to  the recommended replacement mechanism. How does one create a systems setting bundle for their tvOS application? Or  if those are no longer supported, what's the replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with someone at Apple who told me that while the documentation is no longer being updated, it is still the correct way to do what I need. However, they have changed how it is represented in Xcode. Now, instead of creating a new target, you simply create a new file, and under "Resource", there's a "System Settings" file type:

[image: The "New File" sheet in Xcode showing the tvOS tab with the Resource file type "System Settings" selected.]

If you select it, it puts a bundle into your project like this:

[image: The project navigator showing a bundle and its contained files newly added by Xcode]